# Trying to reduce memory allocations, what are the tricks to overloading operators?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

I have written out my class with overloaded operators but I am trying to reduce the amount of memory allocations (as shown by valgrind on Linux). I understand that in certain instances that the copy constructor is called to make a local copy of an object for the function but I'm unsure which situations. As it stands I'm making a new object in each case so I feel that I could get away with ridding some of the "new" calls if I were to make use of the already copied pieces. Below are my operator+ and operator+= for reference.

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator+
// Adds two Poly objects
Poly Poly::operator+(const Poly& rhs) const {
    //case where rhs has more terms
    if (maxExponent < rhs.maxExponent) {
        Poly temp(rhs);

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxExponent; i++) {
            temp.polynomial[i] += polynomial[i];
        }

        return temp;
    }
    else {
        Poly temp(*this);

        for (int i = 0; i <= rhs.maxExponent; i++) {
            temp.polynomial[i] += rhs.polynomial[i];
        }

        return temp;
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator+=
// Adds and assigns two Poly objects
Poly& Poly::operator+=(const Poly& rhs) {
    *this = *this + rhs;
    return *this;
}
```

Here is my operator= in case the tricks depend on this:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator=
// Assigns a Poly object to another
const Poly& Poly::operator=(const Poly& other) {
    if (&other != this) {
        delete[] polynomial;
        maxExponent = other.maxExponent;
        polynomial = new int[maxExponent + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxExponent; i++) {
            polynomial[i] = other.polynomial[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: C++11 move semantics would help a ton.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `Poly temp(rhs);`?? Is rhs not already a copy? Why call the copy constructor on rhs? Just work with rhs directly.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames

Haha glad you brought that up as I was just thinking about that. Only issue is that I have it declared as const in both operator+= and operator+. I read elsewhere that this was proper convention. If I remove the consts I'm able to work directly with it and it seems to run without issue. Seems as though this eliminates any possibility of operators that include ints so that without the consts the compiler isn't able to add Poly + 15 (for example).

Comment: I implement my operators as follows: http://ideone.com/QPdE2G

Answer (score 2):

The technique you are looking for is called "expression templates".

Your `operator+` takes two `Poly&` objects, and returns a `should_be_added< Poly&, Poly& >`.  If you add again, it returns a `should_be_added< should_be_added<Poly&, Poly&>, Poly& >` (or possibly `should_be_added< Poly&, Poly&, Poly& >` if you know things commute and you prefer things to be flat, but that is extra work).

`should_be_added` then has a conversion-to-`Poly`, or `Poly` has an implicit `should_be_added< T, U >&&` constructor (with efficient `move` these two are equivalent).  At that point, you have at compile time the complete tree of expressions you are assigning to your `Poly`.  With lots of work and care, you can efficiently build a single output value.

A good way to start is to start with your `operator+=(Poly const& o)` and `operator+=(Poly&& o)` and similar "mutating" operators.  These primitives can make writing other operators efficiently much easier.

You probably want to write a custom `Poly& operator=( should_be_added<T,U>&& src )` so that it reuses any memory in the existing `Poly` object.  An easy way to do this is to have a method in `should_be_added` that says `Poly result( Poly&& src )`, and implement `operator Poly()` as `operator Poly() const { return result( Poly{} ); }`, and the `operator=` is `{ swap( *this, src.result(std::move(*this)) ); return *this }`

Now, none of this is easy -- expression `template`s are medium-deep `template`-fu.  But the result can be that you can do your mathematical expressions in a natural way, and lose next to nothing.

Note that efficient `move` semantics should be easy for your `Poly` class -- just `move` the internal buffer and clear the source one.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, with `operator+`, conceptually there's not much you can do. You'll need the temporary variable and you'll have to return it by value.

In the second case instead you implementing `operator+=` using `operator+` and therefore making a copy which is then copied within the object itself with `operator=`. This is extremely inefficient.

For the above reasons, often, people prefer to implement `operator+=` first, and then implement `operator+` as:

```
Poly Poly::operator+(const Poly& rhs) {
    return Poly(*this) += rhs;
}
```

Which is the opposite of what you are doing here.

Comment: For clarification purposes, returning by reference (Poly&) calls the copy constructor and creates a local copy for the function?

Comment: @MilanNovaković, in which case? Returning by reference does not automatically calls the copy constructor. If the caller is constructing an object with the reference returned, the constructor called is, indeed, the copy constructor.

Comment: I was trying to decipher this line: "therefore making a copy which is then copied within the object itself with operator=" but I get it now.  Is it necessary in the revised operator+ that it calls the copy constructor "Poly(*this) += rhs" why can't I just pass "*this += rhs"?

Comment: Actually Jeff it looks like your original way was proper. Without the call to the copy constructor there it'll actually change the objects in the call so that C = A + B would result in C and A being the added object whereas with the copy constructor it leaves A and B as is and only C is the added one.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to reimplement Poly class with following idea: let's make it impossible to modify field 'polynomials' and make it shared across copies of same Poly using shared_ptr. This way we can have O(1) copy operator while operator+ is still O(n) - with possibility of O(1) in optimistic case :)

Let's also use std::vector instead of table and be careful about our public interface. In return we get:

- smaller memory consumption
- no code duplication
- no need to implement copy constructor; default will work just fine :)

Forgive my sloppy implementation of operator<<. I left out implementation of optimistic case for operator+ as an exercise to the reader :).

Implemented using c++11, because I am not a masochist.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

class Poly {

public:
    Poly() : polynomial_(NULL) {}

    Poly(std::initializer_list<double> il)
    {
        polynomial_.reset(new std::vector<double>(il.begin(), il.end()));
    }

    unsigned max_exp() const
    {
        return polynomial_ ? polynomial_->size() : 0;
    }

    Poly operator+(const Poly& o) const
    {
        const bool has_bigger_exp = max_exp() > o.max_exp();
        const Poly & poly_big     = has_bigger_exp ? *this : o;
        const Poly & poly_small   = has_bigger_exp ? o : *this;

        auto * tmp = new std::vector<double>(*poly_big.polynomial_);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < poly_small.max_exp(); ++i) {
            tmp->at(i) += poly_small.polynomial_->at(i);
        }

        Poly ret_obj;
        ret_obj.polynomial_.reset(tmp);
        return ret_obj;
    }

    Poly& operator+=(const Poly& o)
    {
          *this = *this + o;
          return *this;
    }

private:

    std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<double>> polynomial_;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Poly& obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Poly& obj)
{
    if (obj.max_exp() == 0) {
        os << "0" << std::endl;
        return os;
    }

    for (unsigned i = obj.max_exp()-1; i > 0; --i) {
        double param = obj.polynomial_->at(i);
        if (param != 0) {
            os << param << " * x^" << i << " + ";
        }
    }

    os << obj.polynomial_->at(0) << std::endl;
    return os;
}

int main() {

    Poly a = {1, 2, 3};
    Poly b = {4, 5};
    Poly c = a + b;
    Poly d;

    std::cout << a << b << c << d;
    a += {1, 1};
    std::cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `new std::vector`?

Comment: I can't modify existing vector, because it might be shared with different object. However, I don't need to create new vector whenever I copy Poly objects - this way, I avoid allocating duplicate vectors in memory :)